# How to determine the holomorphic extension of $f(z)=\frac{\operatorname{Log}(z)}{z-1}$ in a nbhd of $z=1$?

Tags: complex-analysis

How to determine the holomorphic extension of $f(z)=\frac{\operatorname{Log}(z)}{z-1}$ in a nbhd of $z=1$?

I would expand $\operatorname{Log}(z)$ and $\frac{1}{z-1}$ to be Taylor series, but then how to rearrange the terms so that we can say the principal part is $0$? And hence the point $z=1$ is removable. Once we show that $z=1$ is removable, what are the ways to determine the holomorphic extension of $f$, and why do they work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We have geometric series:
$$ \dfrac{1}{1+x}=1-x+x^2-x^3+...=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}(-1)^nx^n.$$
Take integral of that; integration term by term (constant of integration is zero):
$$ln(1+x) =\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}(-1)^n\dfrac{x^{n+1}}{n+1} = \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}(-1)^{n-1}\dfrac{x^{n}}{n}.$$
Let $x=z-1$, then we have:
$$ ln(1+z-1)=ln(z)=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}(-1)^{n-1}\dfrac{(z-1)^{n}}{n}=\dfrac{z-1}{1}-\dfrac{(z-1)^2}{2}+\dfrac{(z-1)^3}{3}-...$$
Now we have:
$$ \dfrac{ln(z)}{z-1}=1-\dfrac{(z-1)}{2}+\dfrac{(z-1)^2}{3}-...$$
Principal part is now obivously zero.
We have new function $g(z)$ that has no singularity at $z=1$:
$$g(z) = 1-\dfrac{(z-1)}{2}+\dfrac{(z-1)^2}{3}-... $$
which is analytic. And analytic functions are also holomorphic therfore g(z) is holomorphic. What is difference between $f(z)$ and $g(z)$? Obviously they are same when $z \neq 1$. But $f(z)$ is problematic at $z=1$ while $g(z)$ is at $z=1$ has no problems (it is natural expansion of $f(z)$).

Comment: Why did you choose to use the geometric series to find the series representation of $Log(z)$? Can we use the formula $\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{f^{(n)}(z_0)}{n!} (z-z_0)^n$?

Answer (score 0):

Hint: $\log z = \log (1+(z-1))= (z-1)-(z-1)^2/2 + (z-1)^3/3 - \cdots $

Comment: Why we don't use $\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{f^{(n)}(1)}{n!} (z-1)^n$ to calculate the Taylor expansion of $Log(z)$?

Comment: Sure, use it, I'm just reminding you that it holds. Once you have  that, you're neary done.

Answer (score 0):

Since $\lim_{z\to1}\frac{\ln z}{z-1}=1$, we have a removable singularity and can use [Riemann's theorem](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Removable_singularity#Riemann's_theorem).

The extension $g$ will be $1$ at $z=1$, and agree with $\frac{\ln z}{z-1}$ on $D\setminus \{1\}$.

The link contains the method for finding $g$'s power series.